# How to store seesion data in magento onepage controller?

Tags: magento, session, checkout, php

Want to store a variable in session in Onepage controller at saveShippingMethodAction()

method and also want to get the value in saveOrderAction() or review.phtml or payment.phtml

I have tried in payment.phtml file, it's worked. But when i set session data from controller file can't get it at phtml file.

**My code:-** 
OnepageController at saveShippingMethodAction() :-

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMySessionVariable($variable);
```

**payment.phtml:-**

```
$myValue  =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMySessionVariable();
Zend_Debug::dump($myValue);
```

Comment: Mostag, magento cannot get sesstion until content is rendering...

Comment: Suppose,i you save data in saveshippingmethod action ,the session  will get in review if  review tab content is refreshed.

Comment: That means when onepage checkout page is load then totals steps (billing,shipping, ....,payment,order.phtml ) is loaded once?
If yes then why below code comment is saying Content loaded dynamically  ???
<div class="order-review" id="checkout-review-load">
    <!-- Content loaded dynamically -->
</div

Comment: Pls , make me help.....how can i solve this ???

Comment: try to call an ajax from review tab,when we goes to  review and ajax will return session value